# Laravel package not completely removed

Tags: laravel, composer-php, package

I installed a PayPal package `sirmklive/paypal` then removed the package from `composer.json`, did composer update and it was removed. I installed PayPal php sdk, works on my localhost then when I pulled updates to my server I got this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Class 'Srmklive\PayPal\Providers\PayPalServiceProvider' not
>   found

Comment: You have to install the packages on your server as well.

Comment: I use git to update my server so basically it's meant to just work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this.

Change permission settings for /bootstrap/cache
Deleted the existing cache files and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed it from config/app.php file which you have added after inserted the package???

And then run the command

```
php artisan config:ca
```

Comment: I have, but seems not to be solving a thing... when I clear my cache locally then push to live server I think it's meant to work

Comment: On server also you need to clear the config. If you have push it before!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  I got it fixed...

Ran: 
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:cache

Did
composer du on server too but still didn't work...  I had to navigate to /bootstrap/cache then deleted the cache files there,  worked immediately.